# how to create an OTP password generated and to be sent to email

Tags: php, sql, email, one-time-password

I have the following code. it generates an `OTP password` locally and displays it on the screen. I would like the password to be sent to email address of the user who would have logged in.

The code is as follows

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username = "'.$_POST['username'].'" AND password = "'.$_POST['password'].'" LIMIT 1', $connection); 

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    $rand= rand(00000000,99999999);

     mysql_query('UPDATE user SET otp="'.$rand.'" WHERE username = "'.$_POST['username'].'" LIMIT 1', $connection); 

      print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
      print 'alert("The OTP is '.$rand.' . Please remember otp for second level of authentication.")'; 
     print '</script>'; 
}
else
{
    mysql_query('UPDATE user SET loginfails= loginfails + 1 WHERE username = "'.$_POST['username'].'" LIMIT 1', $connection);
//  header("Location: loginerror.php");
```

Comment: You can create separate table for OTP with three column user_id, password, and flag used..and for generate password create random number and insert it into this table with user_id and send it to user in mail.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` as they are deprecated, have major security holes, and have been removed in PHP 7. You should use, `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.